# C# - DataGridView, Vertical Scrollbar doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, datagridview, vertical-scrolling

I have a DataGridView in TabControl and I load data from a file, then the file is parsed, and lastly the parsed data are loaded in dgv. Sometimes a problem with the vertical scrollbar occurs. Although the amount of data are higher than they could be visible in dgv, the vertical scrollbar is disabled.

I cannot figure out how it happens. I think it's probably a bug in .NET  because it occurs randomly, sometimes the scrollbar is enabled, sometimes is disabled. I couldn't find out how to simulate this problem. If I maximize and minimize a form with the dgv then the scrollbar is enabled.

It isn't such a big problem but I'm just curious if it can be solved.

I cannot share all code but I think I cannot do anything wrong the main part of setting datasource to dgv:

ControlPresenter:

```
public List<Record> ListEA
        {
            get { return listEA; }
            private set
            {
                listEA = value;
                mainForm.SetDataSourceEA(value);
            }
        }
private List<Record> listEA;
```

MainForm:

```
public void SetDataSourceEA(List<Record> listEA)
{
  Invoke(new Action(() => { eaDataGridView.DataSource = listEA; }));            
}
```

Picture with the disabled vertical scrollbar:
[image]

Edit:
Now, I have noticed that the problem occurs only when I'm in other TabPage than where the datagridview is so I have tried solving with this function (with help Habib):

```
private void tabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            if (sender is TabControl)
            {
                var tabControl = (TabControl)sender;
                var datagridviews = tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>();
                datagridviews.Select(x => { x.PerformLayout(); return false; }).ToList();
            }            
        }
```

And it seems that the problem was solved.

Comment: which .net version your are using ?

Comment: 4.6.1 but I tried it on 4 .NET version and it's same.

Comment: can you try calling dataGridView.PerformLayout(); after binding and check the  AutoSize and Scrollbars properties also

Comment: I have tried it now, but it didn't help. I have edited my question and I have probably solved the problem. Thank you for your note about Performlayout. I haven't know it.